# Testing Values in Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

Is there a way to test and see if there are a certain amount of duplicate numbers in an array list without converting to boolean.

```
Example: [ 1 , 3, 3, 3, 4]
output: Wow you have " 3 " number 3's.
```

I have two cases that I'm working on:
1:

```
for(int i=0; i < 5; i++){
    if (dice[i]!=userKeep) {
       dice[i]=rand()%6+1;
    }
}
```

I want to see if I have 4 dice the same value and if I do return a statement true. (which is easy once you get the if statement or whatever setup.

My instructor told me for the straight and full house it would be easiest to do  boolean array which will only contain true-false, statements. Then the final statement if they have a straight or full house it will only have one false statement.

So I only care that there are 3 duplicated numbers of three so I want to print out there is 3 numbers of 3.

Can this only be accomplished by converting to an array boolean?

Comment: *Is there a way to test and see if there are a certain amount of duplicate numbers in an array list without converting to boolean.* - Yes!

Comment: Hint: Calculate the frequencies of the elements in the list. :)

Comment: So I know it would be some kind of if statement, guidance would be appreciated! Should I mention this should be a basic intro can't used advanced techinques.

Comment: Iterate through the list once; use another array to store the frequency of each element in the list.

Comment: Use `std::map<int, int>` to store the count of each value.

Comment: So if we get that to work, how can we compare say number 3 only, without printing out the numbers.

Comment: @noreturn Who are you addressing the question to?

Comment: @noreturn *without converting to boolean* Why would you need to convert to boolean? *What* would you need to convert to boolean? What is an *array boolean?* The quickest way to answer these questions is to post the code you have with the "array boolean-ness."

Comment: @jpaugh I think for my case which is Yahtzee, making a boolean for the straight is not the easiest way. I still can't get it to compile and run. :(

Comment: @noreturn While I am an experienced coder, I can't make any sense of what an *array boolean* is. Even if your code doesn't work, it could at least help others figure out where you're coming from. Add it to your question.

Comment: @jpaugh I added two cases, one on the one I'm working on right now, then one I can do for more points and what he kinda explained to me how to do the boolean array.

Comment: Can anyone give me a more tailored solution to what I'm trying to do w/ my dice example?

Answer (score 1):

The code for displaying the duplicate number with their frequency is as follows:

```
 #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int len;cin>>len;//number of elements in array
        int arr[len];
        int check[100]={0};//maintain a array to keep frequency of each number
        int max=0;//the maximum value of all the elements in the array is stored to further check the duplicate number in "Check" array to that point only
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            cin>>arr[i];
            check[arr[i]-1]++;
            if(max<arr[i])max=arr[i];
        }
        for(int i=0;i<max;i++)
        {
            if(check[i]>1)cout<<i+1<<" is duplicate with frequency "<<check[i]<<endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `cin>>len; int arr[len];` how is this supposed to work?

Comment: @KillzoneKid https://ideone.com/c8XoZX  Tell me if you need more clarity

Comment: C++14! that explains it ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use map to keep count of all elements including dupes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <map>

int main()
{

    std::array<int, 5> array = { 1, 3, 3, 3, 4 };
    std::map<int, int> map;

    // analyse
    for (size_t i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i)
    {
        int key = array[i];

        if (map.find(key) != map.end())
            map[key]++;
        else
            map[key] = 1;
    }

    // print out dupes
    for (auto dupe : map)
    {
        if (dupe.second > 1)
            std::cout << "Wow you have " << dupe.second << " number " << dupe.first << "'s" << "\n";
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: i think `if(dupe.second > 1) {cout << ...}` is much clearer

Comment: @pm100 agree. Changed